# Trying to install open source software from Github on server

Tags: git, command-line, npm, bower

I'm used to using widgets to install third party software on my site which is obviously just copy/paste the given html, but there's some software I want to install from Github and the ReadMe file states:

> To Run:
>
> git clone https://github.com/Shapeshift-Public/ShapeShift-Skeleton
> cd ShapeShift-Skeleton
> npm install
> bower install
> node dev-server.js
>
> then go to localhost:3000 in browser

I don't want a step by step, just general guidance related to the concept.  What am I being instructed to do? I expected to simply be able to reference the index file from a page in my site and it'd pull up the pop up referenced here, instead I just get a blank screen, and I suspect it's because I don't have a clue what the above means. Apologies to anyone rolling their eyes.

Answer (score 0):

The following should get you started:

1. First install git on your server.
2. from a command line (or if its easier for you install a git tool like tortoise git) execute git clone https://github.com/Shapeshift-Public/ShapeShift-Skeleton
3. install node on your server https://nodejs.org/en/
4. from the command line cd into (or open the command line in) the cloned it repository on your server and then execute npm install bower
5. execute npm install node-dev-server

Note I did not test this, and there may be some slight syntax changes necessary for your OS/etc. but hopefully this helps get you started. Also, after you have done this, there is likely some steps necessary to actually launch this server, I would consult the documentation of ShapeShift-Skeleton and node-dev-server on how to do this.

Comment: Thankyou!  I think it's still going to be fun and games, but this is enough to get me moving in the right direction.

Comment: Any chance you could ++ my answer or accept it if it works for you? Thanks, shameless promotion I know. Oh and if you run into any snags, comment back here and I can probably provide another tip or two.

Comment: Gladly, though I've just been notified my ++ wont publicly display until I've got a rep score of 15.